# How to revert chmod on root directory?

Tags: linux

We have a fresh server setup where a team member exidently has changed the rights for other and group users for the entire root directory.

```
chmod -R go-rwx /
```

This has lead to the fact that e.g. nobody exept of root can login anymore.

Is there an easy way to revert this? It looks to me as this is impossible as there are many folders affected.

The system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: It gave additional information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and fastest way is to backup the user files and reinstall the operating system.

Of course if you have time you can find very similar to your system and grab the rights of every file and then apply to this system, but....